# Initializing local variable with an if statement using scanner

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, java.util.scanner

```
public class calGrades 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int choice = 0;
        while(choice != 4)
        {
            int size; 
            Scanner sizeScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            /* In the grades array, I get an error telling me that the local variable has not 
            yet been initialized. I want to initialize it using the scanner inside the if 
            statement*/ 
            int[] grades = new int[size]; 

            System.out.println("-----MENU-----");
            System.out.println("1) Enter size");
            System.out.println("2) Enter grades");
            System.out.println("3) Calculate average");
            System.out.println("4) Exit program.");

            Scanner choiceScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = choiceScanner.nextInt();

            if(choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter size");
                sizeScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                size = sizeScanner.nextInt();
            }
            if(choice == 2)
            {
                /*If i initialize size = 0, and then try the print statement 
                below, it will print out a 0 instead of whatever is read 
                into it via the scanner. */
                System.out.println(size)
                System.out.println("Enter grades: "); 
                Scanner gradeScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //I get the same error here in my for loop.
                {
                    grades[i] = gradeScanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialize variable 'size' inside of the first 'if' statement. If i initialize the variable in there, it does not change the actual value of size. I undertand that it is outside of the scope, but I do not know how to get it to store in there. This also creates problems with my grades array since I need to know the size of 'size' to set the size of the array. The error I get is: The local variable size may not have been initialized Java(536870963)

Comment: Most people will use `int size = -1;` using what programmers refer to as a [magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).  Then later, if you need, you can check (guard) for the `-1` value in code to ensure your program works.

Comment: You might also want to declare `size` outside the loop

Comment: Please don't make multiple scanners for `System.in`.  If you want to read from `System.in`, then create your `Scanner` right at the beginning of your program, and just use the same `Scanner` over and over.

Comment: @tresf the issue with that is that I need size to be a positive integer, since it dicatates the size of the array used. Size has to be greater than or equal to 1, but if I initiailize it in the beginning, then it wont change after a value is inputed via the scanner.

Comment: @ThumChoonTat I have tried that and I still run into the same error. The issue is with trying to initialize it in the first if-statement. I need the size to be set as the input being taken in.

Comment: You declared `size` inside your `while` loop. Next time through the loop you get a new `size` variable, and the old value is lost. Declare `size` *before* the `while` loop instead.

Comment: @OleV.V. Awesome. That worked! Thank you so much! I have another question. Would my grades[] array also go on the outside? I've tried putting it inside and outside the while loop but I can't get it to properly store data. If I have it outside the while loop,I get an out of bounds error after the first entry. If i keep it inside the while loop, It takes in all the data for the size of the arrat but sets it to 0. Think you could help me on that?

Comment: It needs to go outside so you can calculate the average after the user has previously entered the grades. However you can instantiate it (`grades = new int[size]`) only after the user has entered a size, so somewhere inside the loop.

Comment: @OleV.V. I was able to get it fixed. You were a big help on helping me understand this a bit more. Thanks so much!